# Python how to delete list of items with a blacklist not to delete

Tags: python

I have a utility to delete a list of projects, but I want to know how I can add a black list filter of projects not to delete.

This is what I have right now, I run the script a few times changing the if "Languages" in project: line to delete different projects.

```
def delete_projects():
    projects = get_projects()
    # black_list = [some list of projects that I would like to delete but don't have an exact file name (i.e. "order-*")]
    for project in projects:
    if "Languages" in project:
         delete_project(project)
```

I would like to make it so I can just get the list of projects and use the black_list to check for projects with names LIKE xyz* not to delete. How can I do something like this?

Thanks!

Update: this is just my current thought of implementation. Would it be better to implement it with a regular expression and deleting the project that does not match the regular expression? I would need help with the regular expression if that is the way to go.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want items in the blacklist to be deleted or not deleted? The code implies the former, but your statement "I want to know how I can add a black list filter of projects not to delete" implies the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
black_list_of_regex = ['order-.*', 'normal_name']
print([project for project in projects for reg in black_list_of_regex if re.match(reg, project)])
```

Remember if you want to match full name you should use start/end string regexp `^`, `$` in your regular expressions

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Tomek, just took a little to digest the list comprehension, but awesome answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's relatively simple to create a new list containing only the elements whose names are in the blacklist:

```
projects = [project for project in projects if project not in blacklist]
```

When the blacklist contains patterns, however, the condition may need to be more complex. One way to exclude projects that match any blacklist pattern would be

```
projects = [p for p in projects if any(patt.match(p) for patt in blacklist)]
```

This will retain the projects that match at least one of the patterns.

Comment: I believe OP needs projects that contain blacklisted terms as substrings deleted as well.

Comment: Thanks holden, but is there a way I can do it with the blacklist containing, some type of pattern instead of the exact name to preserve? say i have projects like plugins-release, plugins-snapshot, plugins-??? that I want to preserve, and I would like to just use a condition of something like if project_name contains or project_name like something in the blacklist, don't delete. ?

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
projects = [p for p in get_projects() if p in to_keep]
```

If you want to select the objects that are not in a list simply do:

```
projects = [p for p in get_projects() if p not in to_exclude]
```

Note that this will work with exact matches. If you want to handle substrings, you can do this:

```
projects = [p for p in get_projects() if not any(substr in p for substr in to_exclude)]
```

Comment: This solution shares the same problem as holdenweb's solution. The OP has stated this needs to work with substrings as well.

Comment: Adding the solution for substrings as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
BLACKLIST = {'languages'}

def delete_projects():
    projects = get_projects()
    for project in projects:
       if any(term in project for term in BLACKLIST):
         delete_project(project)
```

As an aside, I would highly recommend first running the code with `delete_project(project)` line commented out and replaced with a print of a project string representation to make sure you're deleting the right projects before doing it for real ;)

Comment: There is no need to use `any`. In fact, it makes the algorithm O(n^2). If blacklist is a set, you can just just do `if project in blacklist: delete_....`, and it stays O(n)

Comment: How would you handle substrings?

Comment: @Karin, yes I definitely do that but just wanted to keep the code block as small as possible... (= I've learned the hard way.

Comment: @Karin yup, you're right. I missed that point. I did not understand that the OP wanted to check substrings as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `projects` are strings, and you have a `blacklist` then you can do:

```
set(projects) - set(blacklist)
```

You can create the black list by:

```
blacklist = [project for project in projects if 'Languages' in project]
```

**Another** option, without a blacklist

```
filter(lambda project: "Languages" not in project, projects)
```

**EDIT**

If you need to save projects that have a certain pattern, I would go with a regexp:

```
import re

pattern = '^XYZ.*'

projects = [project for project in projects if re.search(pattern, project)]
```

And if you have a blacklist of words, then you can do:

```
projects = [project for project in projects if any(pat in project for pat in blacklist)]
```

Comment: projects are strings but in the blacklist (projects to save) I would like to have substrings or a type of matching like, do not delete "plugins*"